# JavaFX FXMLLoader InvocationTargetException and NullpointerException

Tags: java, maven, javafx, model-view-controller

i'm new to java and mvc and trying to do an example witha separation between Business logic and Frontend 
this small app do the following: 
we have a textField and label.
if you write something at the textField then you will become a text at the label ... it makes calculation which letter has the most ocurence.

i'm trying to run the app but i become a Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

Trace :

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\bin\java.exe" "-javaagent:C:\Users\khale\AppData\Local\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2019.1.2\lib\idea_rt.jar=62820:C:\Users\khale\AppData\Local\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2019.1.2\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\jre\lib\charsets.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\jre\lib\deploy.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\jre\lib\ext\access-bridge-64.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\jre\lib\ext\cldrdata.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\jre\lib\ext\dnsns.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\jre\lib\ext\jaccess.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\jre\lib\ext\jfxrt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\jre\lib\ext\localedata.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\jre\lib\ext\nashorn.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\jre\lib\ext\sunec.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\jre\lib\ext\sunjce_provider.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\jre\lib\ext\sunmscapi.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\jre\lib\ext\sunpkcs11.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\jre\lib\ext\zipfs.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\jre\lib\javaws.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\jre\lib\jce.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\jre\lib\jfr.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\jre\lib\jfxswt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\jre\lib\jsse.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\jre\lib\management-agent.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\jre\lib\plugin.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\jre\lib\resources.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\jre\lib\rt.jar;C:\Users\khale\OneDrive\Dokumente\NetBeansProjects\ShowCharWithHighestOccurrence\target\classes" com.mycompany.showcharwithhighestoccurrence.MainApp
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1774)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(FXMLLoader.java:1657)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$KeyHandler.process(Scene.java:3964)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$KeyHandler.access$1800(Scene.java:3910)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processKeyEvent(Scene.java:2040)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.keyEvent(Scene.java:2501)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$KeyEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:217)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$KeyEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:149)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleKeyEvent$352(GlassViewEventHandler.java:248)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:389)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleKeyEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:247)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleKeyEvent(View.java:546)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyKey(View.java:966)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$147(WinApplication.java:177)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:71)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:275)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1769)
    ... 29 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.mycompany.showcharwithhighestoccurrence.javafxFrontend.FXMLController.showCharWithHighestOccurence(FXMLController.java:34)
    ... 39 more
```

Scene.fxml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import java.util.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>

<AnchorPane id="AnchorPane" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="320.0" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/2.2" fx:controller="com.mycompany.showcharwithhighestoccurrence.javafxFrontend.FXMLController">
  <children>
    <TextField fx:id="textField" layoutX="14.0" layoutY="90.0" onKeyReleased="#showCharWithHighestOccurence" prefWidth="209.0" />
    <Label fx:id="outputLabel" layoutX="14.0" layoutY="112.0" prefHeight="32.0" prefWidth="293.0" text="" />
  </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

MainApp.java

```
package com.mycompany.showcharwithhighestoccurrence;

import javafx.application.Application;
import static javafx.application.Application.launch;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;


public class MainApp extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/fxml/Scene.fxml"));

        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        scene.getStylesheets().add("/styles/Styles.css");

        scene.onKeyTypedProperty();
        stage.setTitle("JavaFX and Maven");
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    /**
     * The main() method is ignored in correctly deployed JavaFX application.
     * main() serves only as fallback in case the application can not be
     * launched through deployment artifacts, e.g., in IDEs with limited FX
     * support. NetBeans ignores main().
     *
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

FXMLController.java (Controller)

```
package com.mycompany.showcharwithhighestoccurrence.javafxFrontend;

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.*;


import com.mycompany.showcharwithhighestoccurrence.javafxBusinessLogic.BusinessLogic;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TextArea;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyEvent;

public class FXMLController implements Initializable {



    @FXML
    private TextField textField;

    @FXML
    private Label outputLabel;


    private BusinessLogic businessLogic;



    @FXML
    private void showCharWithHighestOccurence(KeyEvent event) {

        String input, output = "";
        businessLogic.hello();

        if (textField.getText() != null) {
             input = textField.getText();
             if (businessLogic.giveFinalResult(input) != null) {
                 output = businessLogic.giveFinalResult(input);
                 if (output != null) {
                     outputLabel.setText(output);
                 }
             }
        }



    }


    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
        // TODO
    }
}
```

BusinessLogic.java

```
package com.mycompany.showcharwithhighestoccurrence.javafxBusinessLogic;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;

public class BusinessLogic {


    public void hello(){
        System.out.println("helllllo");
    }

    public String giveFinalResult(String text) {

        String input = " ";
        String output = " ";
        if (text != null) {

            input = text.toLowerCase().replaceAll("\\s+", "");

            int[] freq = new int[input.length()];
            int i, j, max, lastFreq;
            lastFreq = 0;

            //Converts given string into character array
            char inputChars[] = input.toCharArray();

            List<Character> maxChars = new ArrayList<>();

            //Count each word in given string and store in array freq
            for (i = 0; i < inputChars.length; i++) {
                freq[i] = 1;
                for (j = i + 1; j < inputChars.length; j++) {
                    if (inputChars[i] == inputChars[j] && inputChars[i] != ' ' && inputChars[i] != '0') {
                        freq[i]++;

                        //Set string[j] to 0 to avoid printing visited character
                        inputChars[j] = '0';
                    }
                }
            }

            //Determine maximum occurring characters
            if (freq.length > 0) {
                lastFreq = freq[0];
            }
            for (i = 0; i < freq.length; i++) {

                max = freq[0];
                if (freq[i] == lastFreq) {
                    max = lastFreq;
                }
                if (max == lastFreq && max < freq[i]) {
                    lastFreq = freq[i];
                    maxChars.add(inputChars[i]);
                    for (Character c : maxChars) {
                        if (c != null) {
                            output = "The most frequent letter is " + c + " with: " + freq[i] + "occurences";
                        }
                    }
                }
                if (lastFreq < freq[i]) {
                    maxChars.clear();
                    maxChars.add(inputChars[i]);
                    for (Character c : maxChars) {
                        if (c != null) {
                            output = "The most frequent letter is " + c + " with: " + freq[i] + "occurences";
                        }
                    }
                }

                if (max > 1 && max == freq[i]) {
                    maxChars.add(inputChars[i]);
                    Iterator iterator = maxChars.iterator();
                    while (iterator.hasNext()) {

                        output = "The most frequent letter are " + maxChars.get(0).toString() + ", "
                                + iterator.next().toString() + " with: " + freq[i] + "occurences";
                    }
                }
            }


        return output;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It happened because you didn’t initialized your business logic field in FXMLController

Replace

```
Private BusinessLogic businessLogic;
```

By

```
private BusinessLogic businessLogic = new BusinessLogic();
```

Comment: thx alot...it works now :))